# A saying for "we are old when we begin to often think about the past"?

Tags: phrase-request, expressions

I remember that I heard of a short yet profound saying that means "we are old when we begin to think about the past" from somewhere (maybe when watching an episode of Desperate Housewives a few years ago). So what is an idiomatic way to say:

> we are old when we begin to often track our memory about the past (and we are young if we still often look into the future).

Comment: "Of all the things I've lost in my life, I miss my mind the most."

Comment: Also, "A man is as old as he feels."

Comment: @DamkerngT. to which the usual (rather risque) reply is usually "*No, a man is as old as the woman he feels!*"

Answer (score 1):

How about, "This is going to make me sound old, but I remember back in the day...
I remember the good old days. When I was a kid, I wished for what might be. As an adult I wish for what might have been. We stop growing and start aging when we stop looking forward and keep looking back".